# How do I notify a user when social login is blocked by a proxy?

Tags: java, facebook, spring, jsf, twitter

I have implemented Facebook Login in my application but when i tested my application in my office Facebook Login is not working because Facebook is blocked in my company but it look like odd when i got following exception

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Can anyone tell how to tell user that Facebook is block in your Network so better to login with other login type like Twitter or Gmail or website Login.?

Answer (score 0):

```
try{     
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{your-app-id}',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}catch(err){
    //inform users not able to connect to facebook
}
```

Comment: I did not get What exactly you are trying to do here in my application no any Single Line of JS i wrote, because using JSF+Spring